# Apache Beam connection with Kerberos Enabled HDFS Cluster Sample Java Code

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-beam

I am Trying to connect to Kerberos enabled HDFS cluster from Apache Beam facing issues Want to Read from HDFS file and write can someone ping a sample working code. Attaching sample code snippet.
Language used -- Java

Am using Kerberos configurations still getting access control exception

I have referred --
[How to read hdfs files into apache beam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458226/how-to-read-hdfs-files-into-apache-beam)

Comment: I don't see a sample code snippet. Can you edit your post with the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Finally it got resolved you just have to add few properties related Kerberos authentication and also few Hdfs properties like core site file location/ Hdfs site location/ add Hadoop home path/ add user information for passing principal and keytab location  and build your beam pipeline by passing these configurations.

Also if you are running beam pipeline in Spark Runner mode try to use spark- submit command instead of Java -cp command
Refer below link for code
[How to read hdfs files into apache beam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51458226/how-to-read-hdfs-files-into-apache-beam)

Just add configurations for Kerberos it will work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).